# Calculating keno odds?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In keno, the casino picks 20 balls from a set of 80 numbered 1 to 80. Before the draw is over, you are allowed to choose 10 balls. What is the probability that 5 of the balls you choose will be in the 20 balls selected by the casino?

My attempt: The total number of combinations for the 20 balls is $80\choose20$. However, I get stuck at the numerator. I thought it will be $\binom{80}{10}\binom{10}5$ but that's wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: To choose exactly 5 balls from the 10 you picked, they must choose 5 from the 10 you picked, and 15 from the 70 you didn't pick.  But I'm not sure they mean "exactly five."  I think it's more likely they mean "at least five."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to think about this is to realize that the casino must choose $5$ balls from the $10$ that you chose and $15$ balls from the $70$ that you didn't choose. So:
$$P = \frac{\binom{10}{5} \binom{70}{15}}{80\choose 20} \approx 0.0514...$$

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality, assume the casino picks balls 1 to 20. Then for the stated scenario to happen:

- Five of your picks are within $[1,20]$: $\binom{20}5$ ways
- The other five are within $[21,80]$: $\binom{60}5$ ways

There are $\binom{80}{10}$ picks altogether, so the probability that five balls match is
$$\frac{\binom{20}5\binom{60}5}{\binom{80}{10}}=0.0514\dots$$

Comment: I would have sworn this was backwards -- that you had to do it as in bames's solution, but it's correct.  Excellent.